# Photoshop to glow specific color only (color-selective glow)

Tags: photoshop-effects

Is there a way to let/make Photoshop 2020 glow specific/picked selected color in the image only?

Like I know there is plenty of glow plugins or action files etc., but none of them - at least those I am aware of - can do this, that is to select very specific color and let it glow with specified intensity.

I mean I do not want any masking, just purely select an image in Photoshop, select color I want to glow and done...

Just to clarify things even further to avoid misunderstandings: I am not saying to pick a color of the glow, but to pick a color in the image that that only color would emit glow. That is something like possible color-selective glow? Something like this:
[image]

When I think about it, there could be just 3 parameters for such plugin:

- color that should glow (pick from an image with a color picked)_
- color tolerance (set value form 0-100% how exact the color selection for the glow should be)
- intensity (how strong the glow should be, prolly 0-100%)

Is there something like this at all?

Or could this even be done via scripting? In such case, as I already done some PS scripts before, I could do it myself somehow?

Comment: What is wrong with using the Inner and Outer Glow Layer Style? [Use Photoshop to apply effects and styles to your layer content and make non-destructive edits](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/layer-effects-styles.html). Can you show an example of what you're trying to achieve and what you have tried doing?

Comment: "....specific selected color only" - this one, AFAIK you cannot select just a specific color and let glow just that one, can you? I am not saying to pick a color of the glow, but to pick a color in the image that that only color would emit glow.

Comment: So you want to select a specific color in an image and only that color glows in the image?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: Try checking out the plugin Lumiere. This seems to do what you want, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to Select -> Color Range, choose the color in the image you want to make glow. Change the "Fuzziness" slider to get more or less colors that are similar to your selection.
2. With the color selected, make a copy of your selection into a new layer by pressing "CTRL (Windows) / CMD (Mac) + J".
3. Add an Outer Glow Layer Style to the new layer, set the blending mode to Linear Dodge (Add)

Comment: Unfortunately, as I wrote in my post question, I do not want any sort of masking, nor selecting the specific color prior the effect, cos the image s are huge (6000x4000px) and full of somewhere smaller, somewhere bigger parts of a specific color. That is not what I am searching for, that way I could doing it simply by masking...sorry, but thanks for effort! It should be really select image, pick color, set amount of glow, bum - done.

Comment: Anyway, I did try your solution, in fact if I could set in SELCT>SIMILAR the tolerance, it could work, but now when I do that it select bunch of colors not correcponding to the selection, like I select exactly what you see in the post image, that is like halucinogene green and it selects even yellow etc., if that could be somehow finetuned maybe I could use it, hm?

Comment: Your question specifies "to pick a color in the image that that only color would emit glow." This is exactly what @AndrewH solved in his answer. There is no masking involved, and if you don't want to select the color to glow then how is Photoshop to know what it is you are trying to do? The size of the image is immaterial. You could use Select > Color Range instead of Magic Wand, and the end result is the same. You seem to be needlessly complicating things instead of using a simple method.

Comment: @fafa, a computer selected mask is still a mask. But yah you could alternatively use color range. But if fact your problem is that the semitransparent  thing isnt one color 6000x 4000 is not a big image standard print size stuff.

Comment: Can we somehow finetune the SELECTY>SIMILAR process so that the tolerance would be lower? Cos now it selects also different colors. Maybe instead of Wand Tool use like literaly pixel selection with specific color like Color Picker does?

Comment: @fafa I have changed my answer based off what shashin-ka said, you should use color range to select the colors.

Comment: This new method looks really good! I have just one problem: when I want to do another color selection (in fact there always be 2 neon-like colors, green and orange) but when I try to do that 2nd color range selection I see previous selection still in the Color Range window - why and how to reset it for this new Color Range selection?

Comment: Ah, OK: just to pick new color will reset the previous one...